# Wrong type interface implementation

Tags: go, prisma

I am trying to follow [Prisma's](https://www.prisma.io/docs/get-started/03-build-graphql-servers-with-prisma-GO-g201/) guide to setting up a GraphQL Go server.

**Resolver.go**

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "prismago/hello-world/generated/prisma-client"
)

// Resolver struct
type Resolver struct {
    Prisma *prisma.Client
}

// Mutation MutationResolver
func (r *Resolver) Mutation() MutationResolver {
    return &mutationResolver{r}
}

// Post PostResolver
func (r *Resolver) Post() PostResolver {
    return &postResolver{r}
}

// Query QueryResolver
func (r *Resolver) Query() QueryResolver {
    return &queryResolver{r}
}

// User UserResolver
func (r *Resolver) User() UserResolver {
    return &userResolver{r}
}

type mutationResolver struct{ *Resolver }

func (r *mutationResolver) CreateUser(ctx context.Context, name string) (*prisma.User, error) {
    return r.Prisma.CreateUser(prisma.UserCreateInput{
        Name: name,
    }).Exec(ctx)
}
func (r *mutationResolver) CreateDraft(ctx context.Context, title string, userID string) (*prisma.Post, error) {
    return r.Prisma.CreatePost(prisma.PostCreateInput{
        Title: title,
        Author: &prisma.UserCreateOneWithoutPostsInput{
            Connect: &prisma.UserWhereUniqueInput{ID: &userID},
        },
    }).Exec(ctx)
}
func (r *mutationResolver) Publish(ctx context.Context, postID string) (*prisma.Post, error) {
    published := true
    return r.Prisma.UpdatePost(prisma.PostUpdateParams{
        Where: prisma.PostWhereUniqueInput{ID: &postID},
        Data:  prisma.PostUpdateInput{Published: &published},
    }).Exec(ctx)
}

type postResolver struct{ *Resolver }

func (r *postResolver) Author(ctx context.Context, obj *prisma.Post) (*prisma.User, error) {
    return r.Prisma.Post(prisma.PostWhereUniqueInput{ID: &obj.ID}).Author().Exec(ctx)
}

type queryResolver struct{ *Resolver }

func (r *queryResolver) PublishedPosts(ctx context.Context) ([]prisma.Post, error) {
    published := true
    return r.Prisma.Posts(&prisma.PostsParams{
        Where: &prisma.PostWhereInput{Published: &published},
    }).Exec(ctx)
}
func (r *queryResolver) Post(ctx context.Context, postID string) (*prisma.Post, error) {
    return r.Prisma.Post(prisma.PostWhereUniqueInput{ID: &postID}).Exec(ctx)
}
func (r *queryResolver) PostsByUser(ctx context.Context, userID string) ([]prisma.Post, error) {
    return r.Prisma.Posts(&prisma.PostsParams{
        Where: &prisma.PostWhereInput{
            Author: &prisma.UserWhereInput{
                ID: &userID,
            }},
    }).Exec(ctx)
}
func (r *queryResolver) Users(ctx context.Context) ([]prisma.User, error) {
    return r.Prisma.Users(&prisma.UsersParams{
        Where: &prisma.UserWhereInput{},
    }).Exec(ctx)
}

type userResolver struct{ *Resolver }

func (r *userResolver) Posts(ctx context.Context, obj *prisma.User) ([]prisma.Post, error) {
    return r.Prisma.User(prisma.UserWhereUniqueInput{ID: &obj.ID}).Posts(nil).Exec(ctx)
}
```

Running `go run ./server` generates the following error:

```
cannot use &userResolver literal (type *userResolver) as type UserResolver in return argument:
        *userResolver does not implement UserResolver (wrong type for Posts method)
                have Posts(context.Context, *"prismago/hello-world/generated/prisma-client".User) ([]"prismago/hello-world/generated/prisma-client".Post, error)
                want Posts(context.Context, *"prismago/hello-world/generated/prisma-client".User) ([]*"prismago/hello-world/generated/prisma-client".Post, error)
```

I tried to fix the type error:

```
func (r *userResolver) Posts(ctx context.Context, obj *prisma.User) ([]*prisma.Post, error) {
    return r.Prisma.User(prisma.UserWhereUniqueInput{ID: &obj.ID}).Posts(nil).Exec(ctx)
}
```

Error:

```
cannot use []"prismago/hello-world/generated/prisma-client".Post as type []*"prismago/hello-world/generated/prisma-client".Post in return argument
```

What am I doing wrong?

Related issue: https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen/issues/714

Comment: The error basically says that `[]prisma.Post` is not `[]*prisma.Post`, which is of course correct, those two are indeed different types, and to satisfy an interface your methods must match *verbatim*. Is there something else besides the error message that is not clear?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I might be jumping the gun here since I have no experience in Go. I understand the typing error but I cannot seem to rectify it with my naive attempts to simply adding '*' etc.

Comment: That's exactly how you fix it, by simply adding `*` where it needs to be, well at the least that's how you fix *that* specific error. If the compilation still fails that means you have more than just that problem. Please update your question with the fixed code and with the new error message.

Comment: I updated the question with the new error.

Comment: Apparently `r.Prisma.User(prisma.UserWhereUniqueInput{ID: &obj.ID}).Posts(nil).Exec(ctx)` returns `[]Post` instead of `[]*Post`. If this is generated code, then maybe you should look a bit further into the documentation (there's probably some stuff you can do to make Prisma "compatible" with itself).

Comment: @Carrein the error indicates, as minitauros pointed out, that the type returned from `Exec` is `[]Post`... in that case instead of "adding `*` where it needs to be" you can "remove `*` where it shouldn't be", i.e. instead of changing the return type of the `Posts` method on the `*userResolver` type you can change the return type of the `Posts` method on the `UserResolver` interface from `[]*Post` to `[]Post`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the `generated.go` file interfaces to accept a return of `[]prisma.Post` instead of `[]*prisma.Post`.

Change:

```
type UserResolver interface {
    Posts(ctx context.Context, obj *prisma.User) ([]*prisma.Post, error)
}
```

To:

```
type UserResolver interface {
    Posts(ctx context.Context, obj *prisma.User) ([]prisma.Post, error)
}
```

Comment: It says to not edit because it is auto generated by gqlgen